# Can I create a self-destructing file?

Tags: files, dropbox, delete

I placed a file into my local Dropbox folder. I would like it to exist only temporarily for X numbers of days. After X numbers of days the file should be automatically deleted.

Is it possible to flag a file with an expiration date after which it is automatically deleted?

Comment: There's no built-ins to implement this, as far as I know.

Comment: May be put something like `find /path/to/files* -mtime +<enter no. of days>  -delete` in a cron job

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming your local folder is synced to the remote folder this is possible.  I have done it with a cron entry in Linux with:

```
find /path/to/synchronized/folders -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete files older than 30 days.

Comment: Why not `-delete` instead of `-exec rm {}`?

Comment: either way is fine.  I didn't even know about -delete.

Comment: Dear all, how can I exclude a folder called "Keep" from being deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Unless *DropBox* itself specifically has a feature for this, you cannot do it. You will simply need to remember to delete the file after said number of days.